# How to efficiently manage sitemap.xml for a moderate size website?

Tags: spring-mvc, web, sitemap

There are few concerns regarding this:

1. Where to put the file? Is it generated per request (as an API)? Is it saved on a storage server?
2. When to update the file? Is it every time new content added? Is batch update better?
3. How to update lastmod? Is it that necessary to be precised?

Total URLs I'm thinking is about 10000 existing URLs and possibly 50 URLs daily.
Is there anything else to consider for sitemap.xml?

Answer (score 0):

Search engines don't crawl sitemaps very often, so you can update them by cron once a day.
Put your sitemap.xml in the root folder of your website and add it to search engines tools like Google webmaster. You can also link this file in your robots.txt:

Sitemap: http://example.com/sitemap.xml

If you have more than 50000 pages, divide sitemap into few with limit of 50000 links in each one (e.g. sitemap_1.xml, sitemap_2.xml). Link them together in the main sitemap.xml
If you use PHP you can use my solution: https://github.com/Sunsetboy/sitemaps-generator